# Give an example of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$$\begin{array}{l}T:{P_2}(x) \to {P_3}(x)\\{\mathop{\rm Im}\nolimits} (T) = Sp\{ {x^3} + 1,{x^2},2{x^3} + 2{x^2} + 3\} \end{array}$$

So, $T(v)$ must be linear-dependent on those four vectors.
I tried to express $T(v)$ with four scalars, but couldn't reach much further than that.

I need a direction.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can set: $$T(1)=x^3+1,~~T(x)=x^2,T(x^2)=2x^3+2x^2+3$$ because we are allowed to do this. In fact, there is an [theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/289397/8581) which tells that between two vector space defined on a field $F$, such this unique transformation exists. See [Ittay's proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/289404/8581) for it.

Comment: that's interseting, how can I produce a formula for $T$?

Comment: @AndrePoole: You wanted one direction. ;-) Take a vector in $P_2$ and so $f=c_1+c_2x+c_3x^2$. Now let $T$ to act on $f$.

Comment: I dont want One Direction, I prefer good Classic Rock.

Comment: But seriously, suppose I'm not familiar with this Thm. What would be an alternative solution?

Comment: btw, What you did is using the standard $P(x)$ basis. Right?