# Linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

Let there be a linear transformation $T:R^3\rightarrow R^2$

Is there a linear transformation so that:

$Ker(T)=Span((1,2,1),(0,3,-1))$ and $Im(T)=Span((5,-7))$

Answer: $Dim(V)=Rank(T)+Null(T)=2+1=3$ so by dimension there is now to find $T$

$\begin{pmatrix} a&b&c\\  d&e&f\\ \end{pmatrix}*
\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 2\\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 0\\  0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} a&b&c\\  d&e&f\\ \end{pmatrix}*\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 3\\ -1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$

So I got $\begin{pmatrix} -5b &b &3b\\ -5e&e&3e\\ \end{pmatrix}*\begin{pmatrix} x\\  y\\ z\\ \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 5\\  -7\\ \end{pmatrix}$

How do I continue from here?

Comment: What about $b=5$, $e=-7$?

Comment: @daw I must take a guess at this phase?

Comment: The matrix in your last equation has image equal to the span of the vector $(b,e)^T$... Now it is an educated guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple [Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289397/a-theorem-concerning-unique-linear-mapping-between-vector-spaces-what-does-it-s) to remember is that given a basis $\{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_n\}$ of $V$ and any $n$ vectors $\{\beta_1, \beta_2,.., \beta_n, \}$ in $W$ there **is** exactly one Linear Transformation such that $ T(\alpha_i) = \beta_i$. So you have two simple tasks:

- Find a basis $\{v_1, v_2\} $for $\ker T$ and let $T(v_1) = T(v_2) = \underline {0}$
- You can extend $\{v_1, v_2\}$ by adding one more vector $v_3$ to form a basis for $\Bbb R^3$. Define $T(v_3) = (5, -7)$

This $T$ is uniquely determined and conforms to your conditions.

---

Now I get the feeling you also require the matrix which represents this particular Linear Transformation. The matrix of $T$ relative to the bases $ \{v_1, v_2, v_3\} $ and $\{(0,1), (1, 0)\}$is:
$$ \left({\begin{matrix}
        0 & 0 & 5 \\
        0 & 0 & -7 \\
                \end{matrix}}\right)$$

which you can transform to a matrix in the Standard Ordered Bases using the theory of similar matrices ([see pages 91 - 94](https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lisabeckphotography.com%2FMath%2FTextbooks%2FLinear%2520Algebra%2FLinear%2520Algebra%2520-%2520Hoffman%2520%26%2520Kunze.pdf&ei=bJ0ZVLWDMeT-ygPs5YHACg&usg=AFQjCNFoDLVnmFhhcNOJm7Fj8fkN7k3oZg&bvm=bv.75558745,d.bGQ)). And this will also allow you to find an explicit general equation for $T(x, y, z)$

---

**UPDATE:**

This thread is too long so here is a proper solution. Note that adding another vector would make $\{(1,2,1), (0,3,-1), (0,0,1)\}$ would create a basis (which can be verified by row reduction). Now, as specified above, we define $T$ thus,

- $ T(1,2,1) = (0,0)  $
- $ T(0,3,-1) = (0,0)  $
- $ T(0,0,1) = (5,-7)  $

Such a definition is valid according to the Theorem I have stated above and linked first. Now since the three vectors form a basis there are **unique**scalars $a, b, c$ such that $$ (x, y, z) = a(1,2,1) + b(0,3,-1) + c(0,0,1) \;\; \forall (x, y, z) \in \Bbb R^3 $$

The scalars can be found by solving a simple system of equations.

Now for any $(x, y, z)$ we have,

$$T(x, y, z) = T(a(1,2,1) + b(0,3,-1) + c(0,0,1)) = a T(1,2,1) + b T(0,3,-1) + c T (0,0,1) $$

Substitute for the scalars and $Tv$'s and you would have an explicit formula for $T$ in terms of $ x, y, z $.

Comment: isn't the given vectors are already a basis?

Comment: Absolutely. I was just being general.

Comment: I do not understand how you got to  $$\left({\begin{matrix}
        0 & 0 & 5 \\
        0 & 0 & -7 \\
                \end{matrix}}\right)$$ which equations did you create?

Comment: Its just how you construct the matrix of a Linear Map. You list the coordinates of $T(\alpha_i)$ with respect to the considered basis in $\Bbb R^2$ in the columns.

Comment: But I still do not know $T$

Comment: You know it for the vectors in the basis and that is all you need.

Comment: You mean $\begin{pmatrix} -5b &b &3b\\ -5e&e&3e\\ \end{pmatrix}*\begin{pmatrix} x\\  y\\ z\\ \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\\ \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} -5b &b &3b\\ -5e&e&3e\\ \end{pmatrix}*\begin{pmatrix} x\\  y\\ z\\ \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\\ \end{pmatrix}$ ?

Comment: Not getting your question mate? Note that your method hits a stonewall unless you figure out $ \left({\begin{matrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{matrix}}\right)$ when the vector is not in the span of $\{ (1,2,1), (0,3,-1)\}$

Comment: Yes there is where I stuck, I know that T(x,y,z)=Span(5,-7)=5(1,0)-7(0,1)