# Deducing a formula for (?) linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have the following question:

> Given a certain transformation, determine if this transformation is
>   linear or not. $T(1,0,0)=0,T(2,-1,0)=1,T(3,2,1)=2$

What I think needs to be done is to **deduce a formula** for this transformation and then determine if it linear or not (checking **additive** and **homogeneous** properties).
I'm having hard time understanding how to deduce the formula.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How could you obtain a formula for $T$ from this information without knowing that $T$ is linear ?

Comment: Are you sure you need to deduce a formula **first**? You could check for additivity and homogeneity from the three points you have. If it holds there, you can assume $T$ is linear and only then derive a formula. If $T$ is not linear, 3 points are not enough to deduce $T$ uniquely.

Comment: I'll go with your idea, I might not understood the method of working completly. Let's assume that it's linea- derive a formula and then check whether the formula is linear or not.

Comment: To be more specific, your mapping seems to be ${\mathbb R}^3 \rightarrow {\mathbb R}^1$. Hence, if it is linear, it can be described by 3 coefficients àla $T = <x,t>$, $t \in \mathbb{R}^3$. You are given 3 points which a linearly independent so you just have enough information to compute the coefficients (**knowing** its linear). To check for linearity you would need more. If you have a linearly dependent point $\bar{x}$ that you can write as $\bar{x} =  \alpha_1 x_1+\alpha_2 x_2$ you can check whether $\bar{y} = T(\bar{x}) = T(\alpha_1 x_1+\alpha_2 x_2) = \alpha_1 T(x_1) + \alpha_2 T(x_2)$.

Comment: ok so if i try to sum it up: i have to find 2 points in the span (what you said as compute the coefficients) and then check if these two points are fulfilling additive property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T(x,y,z)=4z-y$ is linear and satisfies the condition.

$T(x,y,z)=y-xy+6z$ isn't linear and also satisfies the condition.

So, we do not have information enough.

### Edit. (response to the comment)

*How did you calculate these formulas?*

If $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are three linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^3$, and $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ are three arbitrary real numbers, then there is a unique linear transformation $T$ from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R$ such that $T(v_1)=\alpha_1$, $T(v_2)=\alpha_2$, $T(v_3)=\alpha_3$. This is a particular case of a general result, which is stated and explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289397/a-theorem-concerning-unique-linear-mapping-between-vector-spaces-what-does-it-s). If you know how to prove it, you can calculate the first formula above. The general proof can be found [here (Theorem 4.4)](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~heilman/teach/lalg2.pdf). Motivated by this proof, we can deal with your particular case as follows.

Find $a_1,a_2,a_3$ (in terms of $x,y,z)$ such that $$(x,y,z)=a_1(1,0,0)+a_2(2,-1,0)+a_3(3,2,1).$$
(This can be done because $(1,0,0)$, $(2,-1,0)$, $(3,2,1)$ are linearly independent.) The answer is $a_1=x+2y-7z$, $a_2=2z-y$, $a_3=z$. So, the unique linear transformation from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R$ that satisfies the condition given in the problem is given by
$$\begin{align}
T(x,y,z)&=T(a_1(1,0,0)+a_2(2,-1,0)+a_3(3,2,1))\\
&=T((x+2y-7z)(1,0,0)+(2z-y)(2,-1,0)+z(3,2,1))\\
&=(x+2y-7z)T(1,0,0)+(2z-y)T(2,-1,0)+zT(3,2,1)\\
&=(x+2y-7z)\cdot0+(2z-y)\cdot1+z\cdot2\\
&=4z-y
\end{align}$$

For the second formula, I did not follow any specific rule. I just tried to find a formula with the term $xy$ such that:

- For $x=1$, $y=0$ and $z=0$ the result is $0$.
- For $x=2$, $y=-1$ and $z=0$ the result is $1$.
- For $x=3$, $y=2$ and $z=1$ the result is $2$.

There are others. Can you find one?

Comment: how did you calculate these formulas?

Comment: @YaronScherf See my edit.