# determining a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

For a linear transformation, the property to be satisfied is:

```
T(cu+dv) = cT(u) + dT(v)
```

But, given a standard matrix for transformation **A** such that the transformation for a vector **x** is: **Ax**, where **A** takes the form: 
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d\\  
e & f\\
g & h
  \end{pmatrix}
$$ .
Is this form of **Ax** sufficient to declare it as a linear transformation, given that the transformation exists. Or, is it necessary to check it for the aforementioned properties?

Comment: Every matrix product is a linear transformation. You don't need to check something.

Comment: I would say the form $Ax,$ understood as matrix multiplication, is sufficient to declare it as a linear transformation, yes.

Comment: Is there any proof of that?

Comment: @lind If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At each linear transformation (for a given basis) correspond a matrix and viceversa (for a given basis) at each matrix correspond a linear transformation. Indeed (it's a theorem) a linear transformation is completely defined once we know how the basis vectors are "transformed" that is once the coefficient of the Matrix are defined.

Comment: can you point me to this theorem on a page or something. If there's a name?

Comment: Take a look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289397/a-theorem-concerning-unique-linear-mapping-between-vector-spaces-what-does-it-s

Answer (score 2):

It should be sufficient. To assure yourself of this, take an arbitrary matrix of arbitrary dimensions, take two arbitrary vectors $u$ and $v$ of finite dimension matching the appropriate dimension of the matrix, and show that the condition $T(cu+c'v) = cT(u) + c'T(v)$ is satisifed. It's a bit tedious, but now you've shown all matrices express linear transformations.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong about what a linear transformation is. You should have written$$T(\alpha u+\beta v)=\alpha T(u)+\beta T(v).$$

It is not clear to me what the rest of your question means, but if you are asking if every map of the form$$(x,y)\mapsto A.(x,y)=(ax+by,cx+dy,ex+fy,gx+hy)$$is linear, then, yes, it is true (assuming that your base field is $F$ and that this is a map from $F^2$ to $F^4$). And it is easy to check.

Comment: It is better to write in comment. As you see it is said that *use comments to ask more information or suggest improvements!*