# How can I prove that the B-matrix of T (a linear transformation) is injective/surjective implies that T is injective/surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra

T is a linear transformation and B-matrix of T with respect to any arbitrary basis.

This seems intuitively true to me because changing the transformation with respect to a new basis shouldn't change anything, but I just want to confirm this. Also, if you can illustrate a proof, that would be great.

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @gimusi I don't really understand either answer.

Comment: At each linear transformation (for a given basis) correspond a matrix and viceversa (for a given basis) at each matrix correspond a linear transformation. Indeed (it's a theorem) a linear transformation is completely defined once we know how the basis vectors are "transformed" that is once the coefficient of the matrix are defined.

Answer (score 0):

A linear transformation is completely determined by the image of a basis that is precisely by its matrix representations in that basis.

Refer also to the related [determining a linear transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2599856/determining-a-linear-transformation?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varphi$ be the canonical coordinate change with respect to $B$, so $T=\varphi^{-1}\circ B\circ\varphi$, if $B$ is injective and $Tx=0$, then $\varphi^{-1}(B\varphi (x))=0$, and hence $B\varphi(x)=0$, then $\varphi(x)=0$, and finally $x=0$.

Can you prove the surjectivity?