# Proof that it is sufficient to define T on basis vectors to determine the whole transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I want to make sure that I am understanding it correctly to only deal with basis vectors when I want to find a linear transformation.

Let ${v_i ... v_n}$  be a basis of V

Thus, for any $x\in V$, $x = \sum c_i*v_i$. This means that $T(x) = \sum c_i*T(v_i)$ meaning that knowing only what T does to the basis vectors is sufficient. Is this a rigorous proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is absolutely correct, once we know $T(v_i)$ we know everything since $\forall x$ we have $x=\sum a_iv_i$.

Comment: And the proof is rigorous as well? If not, how can I make it rigorous?

Comment: @Goldname You need just to write with an order, that is: it is given that $T(v_i)=w_i$ and since $v_i$ is a basis $\forall x_i\in V\implies x=\sum a_iv_i$ (unique) then for linearity $T(x)=T(\sum a_iv_i)=\sum a_iT(v_i)=\sum a_iw_i$.

Comment: What do you mean by with an order? You mean, have my argument be more organized?

Comment: @Goldname Yes exacly, following a logical path describing the set up the hypotesis and the derivation for each step.

Comment: @Goldname Take also a look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289397/a-theorem-concerning-unique-linear-mapping-between-vector-spaces-what-does-it-s