# Find a linear transformation $ \ T \ $ that sends $ \ A \ $to the parallelogram $ \ B \ $

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we are given the unit square $ \  A \ $ in the plane with corners $ \ (0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1)  \ \ and \ \  (0, 1) \ $

Find a linear transformation $ \ T \ $ that sends $ \ A \ $to the parallelogram $ \ B \ $ with corners $ \ (0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 2) \ \  and \ \  (1, 0) \ $.

**Answer:**

$ T(0,0)=(0,0) \\ T(1,0)=(1,2), \\ T(1,1)=(2,2), \\ T(0,1)=(1,0) \ $

From this how to find the linear transformation $ \ T(x,y) \ $ ?

**Help me finding $ \ T(x,y) \ $.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $T(0,0)=(0,0)$, as required for a linear transformation, and $T(1,1)=T(1,0)+T(0,1)$, the definition is consistent and it suffices to consider the linear tranformation such that

- $T(1,0)=(1,2)$
- $T(0,1)=(1,0)$

that is in matrix form with reference to the standard basis

$$T(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\2&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thus $ \ T(x,y)=(x+y,2x) \ $ . My question is- Is $ \ T(x,y) \ $ is unique ?

Comment: Yes exactly. Of course it is unique for the theorem of existence and uniqueness of linear transformations. I will give you some references.

Comment: last question: what is the transformation $ \ T \ $ that send $ \ A \ $ to $ \ A \ $ ?  Is it $ \ T(x,y)=(x,y) \ $ ?

Comment: The identity transformation, represented by the I matrix.

Comment: @yourmath For the uniqueness refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/289397/505767

Answer (score 2):

You know what $T(1,0)$ and $T(0,1)$ are whence
$$
T(x,y)=xT(1,0)+yT(0,1)
$$